# CSS to scroll down image

Tags: css

[On this page](https://www.portal-gestao.com/home-baixo-2.html) I have images with the class: `.moduleItemImage`

These images need to be cropped to have 100% width and 250px height.

I've managed to achieve that somewhat, with this code:

```
.moduleItemImage{
    width: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
    display:block;
    height:250px;
    line-height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, I'd like the image to be centered vertically or to scroll it down a bit, maybe 50px;

Tried vertical-align, margin, etc. but nothing works.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: wich image have that class on your website?

Comment: you best option would be inserting the image via `background-image`\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are expecting. If not, please comment a little more on the problem if needed.

EDIT
Use `object-positon` to alter image position on crop.

```css
.moduleItemImage {

  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  height: 250px;
  line-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.moduleItemImage img {
    object-position: 0px -140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="moduleItemImage">
<img src="https://www.portal-gestao.com/media/k2/items/cache/cc4d19bea0c6bf7034d0923c98a24c20_XL.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The image URL is dinamically generated. The height should be 250px. So I tried adapting your code, but the page looks the same.

Comment: @NunoNogueira i think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Geraldo BLANCO yes!

Comment: @NunoNogueira Glad it helped